# How to use spinner in webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Here is my code,
Code:
http://pastebin.com/cHVThsR5

I am having the spinner here but the spinner keeps rotating. How do I let the app know that the page load is finished? and after all making the spinner invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try making it invisible manually?

```
 if (isInternetPresent) {
            ImageView NoInt=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.NoInternet);
            NoInt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ProgressBar pb = this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar); //Get a reference to your ProgressBar


            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webView.loadUrl("http://glocalkhabar.com");
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Make it invisible
```